# Logic App HTTP action Bad request due to max buffer size

Tags: httprequest, azure-logic-apps

Real quickly I am trying to complete an http action in azure logic app that will send out a get request to return a csv file as the response body. The issue is when I run it I get a "BadRequest. Http request failed as there is an error: 'Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size: 104857600.'". I am not sure how to mitigate this buffer limit or whether I can increase it. I could use some help I really need this csv file returned so I can get it into to blob storage.

Comment: May I know if you have solved this problem?

Comment: Problem is solved thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please try this way:

**1.** In the HTTP action's upper-right corner, choose the ellipsis button (...), and then choose Settings.

[image]

**2.** Under Content Transfer, set Allow chunking to On.

[image]

You can refer to [Handle large messages with chunking in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-handle-large-messages)